# CGPatternGetStep() signature?

Tags: macos, assembly, core-graphics, reverse-engineering, disassembly

Can anybody please explain me the following assembly?

```
_CGPatternGetStep:
    +0  0007fb86  55                      pushl       %ebp
    +1  0007fb87  89e5                    movl        %esp,%ebp
    +3  0007fb89  53                      pushl       %ebx
    +4  0007fb8a  8b4508                  movl        0x08(%ebp),%eax
    +7  0007fb8d  8b504c                  movl        0x4c(%eax),%edx
   +10  0007fb90  8b5850                  movl        0x50(%eax),%ebx
   +13  0007fb93  89d0                    movl        %edx,%eax
   +15  0007fb95  89da                    movl        %ebx,%edx
   +17  0007fb97  5b                      popl        %ebx
   +18  0007fb98  c9                      leave
   +19  0007fb99  c3                      ret
```

I want to find out the step passed in method  CGPatternCreate (
   void *info,
   CGRect bounds,
   CGAffineTransform matrix,
   CGFloat xStep,
   CGFloat yStep,
   CGPatternTiling tiling,
   bool isColored,
   const CGPatternCallbacks *callbacks
);

I want to find xStep and yStep Values? I have CGPatternRef with me. Can above disassembly of function be used for getting xStep and yStep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pushl       %ebp
movl        %esp,%ebp
pushl       %ebx
```

Setup stack frame and save register ebx.

```
movl        0x08(%ebp),%eax
```

Load the first stack argument (from ebp+8) into eax.

```
movl        0x4c(%eax),%edx
```

Load a 32-bit value from the field at offset 0x4C from the address in eax into edx.

```
movl        0x50(%eax),%ebx
```

Load a 32-bit value from the field at offset 0x50 from the address in eax into ebx.

```
movl        %edx,%eax
movl        %ebx,%edx
```

Move the previously loaded values into eax and edx, respectively.

```
popl        %ebx
leave
ret
```

Restore saved register ebx, tear down stack frame and return.

Since the code sets both eax and edx just before returning, we can conclude that the return type is 64-bit. You can also note that the two loads are for consecutive locations (0x4C+4==0x50). So, most likely the first (and sole) argument is a pointer to a structure that has a 64-bit member at offset 0x4C, and the function returns its value.

```
typedef struct _CGPattern
{
 ...
 uint64_t step; // offset 0x4C
 ...
} CGPattern;

uint64_t CGPatternGetStep(CGPattern *pat)
{
  return pat->step;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I am slightly confused. Actuall I am trying to identify the paramenters of the 
CGPatternRef CGPatternCreate (
   void *info,
   CGRect bounds,
   CGAffineTransform matrix,
   CGFloat xStep,
   CGFloat yStep,
   CGPatternTiling tiling,
   bool isColored,
   const CGPatternCallbacks *callbacks
);

It has xStep and yStep. I thought method should return 2 values of xStep and yStep. Have I missed something?

Comment: Then maybe you should ask the actual question from the start... It's quite possible that this functions returns a small structure of two 32-bit values and not one 64-bit value. Without additional context you can't really distinguish the two cases.

Comment: I tested the function uint64_t CGPatternGetStep(CGPattern *pat); It turns out return value is some garbage.

Comment: @MachinTosh: If you're trying to retrieve input values, it's a good guess that what you retrieve will be the same type—in this case, a `CGFloat`. Note that floating-point numbers and integers are not returned the same way. (This is why you need to include all information in the question up front!)